# Assigning static address to device via Cisco ADSM

Tags: firewall, dhcp, cisco-router

(Tried asking this over in Server Fault, but they rejected it because -- despite the Cisco ASA usually being considered enterprise hardware -- they insist home networks are out of bounds. Sigh. My fault for specifying that unnecessary detail.)

On my home network, I have an old Cisco ASA 5510 version 9.1(7)16 firewall box that I'm managing with ADSM 7.6(1).

I have a Raspberry Pi that wants to be located at a specific, stable IP address (setting up a Node-RED bridge for SmartThings), and I'm trying to follow the instructions in https://serverfault.com/questions/115992/configuring-cisco-asa-5510-to-assign-static-ip-address-based-on-mac-address.

`ifconfig` on the Pi reports

```
inet 192.170.1.161  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.170.1.255
inet6 fe80::f9cd:4687:90cd:5da2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
ether b8:27:eb:b7:4a:73  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

The ASDM DHCP Server Table currently reports the device as

```
IP address 192.170.1.161   
Client ID 01b8.27eb.b74a.73
```

Trying to ignore the leading 01 (I'm not sure where it comes from?), I went to the `Configuration > Device Management > Advanced > ARP Static Table` screen and added an entry on the right interface associating IP Address `192.170.1.113` with MAC address b827.ebb7.4a73. I also knocked the ARP Timeout value down to 60 seconds for testing.

I started the Pi rebooting, then went back to `Monitoring > Interfaces > DHCP > DHCP Server Table`, punched Clear, and Refreshed until I saw `01b8.27eb.b74a.73` reappear as a Client ID.

Unfortunately, it has been assigned `192.160.1.160` -- so my attempt to assert a specific address didn't work.

I presume this is a user error. If someone could tell me which foot I'm putting in my mouth that would be greatly appreciated. Is the ARP table the wrong tool? Is there a better/alternative way to tell DHCP to serve a specific address to this Pi? Is that leading 01 the problem, and if so is there a way to overcome it?

Comment: ... and this silence is why I thought it belonged on Server Fault rather than here.

Comment: Further research suggests that newer versions of the ASA firmware -- 9.13(1) and later? -- have the ability to specify static DHCP bindings, but that was simply not supported in the older versions. The only solutions may be to upgrade the firmware (I'm guessing not cheap, this being enterprise hardware), or to drop a newer router into this subnet and manage the addresses from there.

Comment: Current evidence is that assigning static DHCP bindings is a feature added in a later release of the firmware... and that this upgrade may not be available for my box. Workaround would be to drop a more modern router between the Cisco and this subnet and have it manage the DHCP assignment. Or replace the firewall box with a newer surplus Cisco if I can find one.